# Is it possible to set pthread CPU affinity in OS X?

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, pthreads, affinity

In **Linux** there is a **sched_setaffinity()** function defined in **sched.h**, but I can't seem to find anything like that in **Mac OS X 10.6 pthreads** implementation... If it is not possible to set affinity, what is the default policy in **OS X**?

Comment: See this blog: http://yyshen.github.io/2015/01/18/binding_threads_to_cores_osx.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X has [Thread Affinity API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Performance/RN-AffinityAPI/index.html) and you can use it with pthread ID as thread_policy_set(pthread_mach_thread_np(pthreadId), but, as far as I know, there are no APIs like sched_setaffinity.

Comment: What the hell? I took a look at Mac OS X 10.6 SDK's /usr/include/mach/thread_policy.h and found out that the thread_policy_set() / thread_policy_get() functions are commented out! What is the meaning of this?!

Comment: It is really compatible with pthread. Please take a look at /Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/CAPThread.cpp or google "thread_policy_set pthread_mach_thread_np". And thread_policy_set/thread_policy_get are in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/mach/x86_64/thread_act.h . Anyway, these API are not same as sched_setaffinity.